# Cookies in asp.net [inmemory cookie, persistent cookie]

Tags: asp.net

How can I delete the cookie in persistent cookie not abandon()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make it expire:

```
Response.Cookies["cookiename"].Expires = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: ok it is good. but i want to set some time after that time the cookie will expiry automatically according to that time we set. thank u mr.Paul for response.

Comment: ok Mr.Paul i get the answer it is like this
Response.Cookies["flsdfl"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours();
thank u.reply please

Comment: Think you've got it there fella.

Answer (score 0):

Just send a new cookie with the same name and an expiry in the past, or if you want it to change from persistent to session only, send a new cookie with the same name and no expiry.

Comment: how can i write code i saw some books like cookie= datetime.now.day()
some thing like that i don't remember exactly what is that.

Comment: ok Mr.ck i get the answer it is like this
Response.Cookies["flsdfl"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours();
thank u.please reply.